# Why is my program starting to look corrupted?

Tags: c++

I've been working on a temperature converter to refresh a bit before school (in VSCode) and everything was working just fine until I added "system("cls")" and "system("pause")". Now I can maybe get it to repeat once before the output becomes unread-ably scrambled. Below is the function I made the edit to and main as well. nothing changed in all the other functions

```
void fahrenheitToCelsius()
{
    float temperatureInput;
    float temperatureOutput;

    cout << "Fahrenheit to Celsius Converter\n";
    // temperature in
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit\n";
        cin >> temperatureInput;

        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cout << "Invalid input. Please enter a number\n";
            cin.clear(); // Clear the error state
            string dummy;
            getline(cin, dummy);
            cout << "Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit\n";
            cin >> temperatureInput;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
    // formula for conversion
    temperatureOutput = (temperatureInput - 32) * (5.0 / 9);
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    // Output
    cout << "The temperature is: " << temperatureOutput << "C";
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

```
int main()
{
    // Variables
    int mainSelect;

    // clear previous
    // system("cls");

    do
    {
        // Selection list
        cout << "Which temperature converter would you like to use?\n (Please select by typing in the selection number)\n";
        cout << "1. Fahrenheit to Celsius\n";
        cout << "2. Celsius to Fahrenheit\n";
        cout << "3. Kelvin to Fahrenheit\n";
        cout << "4. Kelvin to Celsius\n";
        cout << "5. Fahrenheit to Kelvin\n";
        cout << "6. Celsius to Kelvin\n";
        cin >> mainSelect;
        cout << endl;

        switch (mainSelect)
        {
        case 1:
            fahrenheitToCelsius();
            break;
        case 2:
            celsiusToFahrenheit();
            break;
        case 3:
            kelvinToFahrenheit();
            break;
        case 4:
            kelvinToCelsius();
            break;
        case 5:
            fahrenheitToKelvin();
            break;
        case 6:
            celsiusToKelvin();
            break;
        case 7:
            cout << "Thanks you! Goodbye.\n";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid input, please enter a valid input\n";
            break;
        }
    } while (mainSelect != 7);
}
```

My output looks like this

```
Which temperature converter would you like to use?
 (Please select by typing in the selection number)
1. Fahrenheit to Celsius
2. Celsius to Fahrenheit
3. Kelvin to Fahrenheit
4. Kelvin to Celsius
5. Fahrenheit to Kelvin
6. Celsius to Kelvin
1

Fahrenheit to Celsius Converter
Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit
1
The temperature is: -17.22C
Press any key to continue . . . 
Wumber)
1. Fahrenheit to Celsius
2. Celsius to Fahrenheit
3. Kelvin to Fahrenheit
4s
5in
```

I tried to see if the problem would happen in an IDE I have to use for school so I copied the whole code over there and made sure nothing was commented out and everything seemed to work just fine (aside from nothing clearing).

I did try commenting all of the "system" functions out but the issue continued to persist in VSCode

Is this an issue with using C++ on VSCode?

I can't seem to make sense of what I did to mess such a simple project up so catastrophically

Comment: Those two calls are very Windows-specific, non-portable and a bad habit. Please just don't use them.

Comment: Let's throw your code at Compiler Explorer and turn on some extra diagnostics. https://godbolt.org/z/rbe3b1dTz Well. That didn't work. Looks like you forgot a few headers. https://godbolt.org/z/1v95Y4PKh Huh. Still doesn't work. Hard to make good answers when you have to guess at what's going  wrong and can't test the solutions we come up with..

Comment: Questions asking for debugging help must include a [mre] that demonstrates the issue, according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines. You've not done so. Also, the start to solving these sorts of issues is to step through the code in a debugger to find your logic errors. If you don't know how to use a debugger, now is the perfect time to start learning. There isn't any better tool in a programmer's toolbox.

Comment: The output you've shown includes the output from the system `pause` command. Now, you said that this issue persists if you comment-out _all_ the `system` calls. So then how can the output look like that? Are you saying it does? Is that output you've shown _exactly_ what you get even when you don't call `system("pause");`?

Comment: there is almost certainly no issue with using C++ on VSCode, its probably because a comprehensive IDE does many things under the hood for the user, while VSCode is a more (but not completely) bare-bones text editor.

Comment: As a side-note, you are doing some fiddly input error handling, which is a symptom of other issues. When your input is line-based (as in, the user always presses Enter), then use `std::getline` for everything. You can parse the result with a `std::istringstream`, and you can wrap that stuff up in a very simple function (or even a function template) to greatly simplify your program and make it more robust to weird input conditions.

Comment: Personally I think this is going to be VS Code's terminal being goofy. I don't see anything wrong. Build the program in VS Code, and then run it in a regular terminal window, which I hope is cmd or powershell because if you're running this code anywhere but on a Windows OS, it's just not gonna work right.

Comment: Side note: VS Code's not a particularly good tool to learn C++ with. There are a lot of quirks, configuration isn't quite straight forward (follow the set up documentation to the mother <expletive deleted>ing letter or you're <expletive deleted>ed) and if you can't tell a quirk or misconfiguration from a bug in your code, you're wasting valuable education time.